# Microservice does not receive RabbitMq message

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

When I add a new user to my `IdentiyServerService` the following `MassTransit` code is called:

```
        var newUserCreated = new UserCreated
        {
            UserId = userId.ToString(),
            Name = user.Name
        };
        await _bus.Publish(newUserCreated);
```

My destination is that my `ProfileService` receive this event by `RabbitMq`.

My `RabbitMq` configuration in my `Startup.cs` (IdentiyServerService)

```
private static void ConfigureBus(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                var host = config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });
            });
        }).As<IBus, IBusControl, IPublishEndpoint>().SingleInstance();
    }
```

I start the bus like this

```
//Startup.cs IdentityServerService
var container = containerBuilder.Build();
var busControl = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
busControl.Start();
```

The configuration in my `ProfileService` look quite almost the same. The difference is, that I add an consumer in my `Startup.cs` (ProfileService)

```
                config.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "user_queue", ep =>
                {
                    ep.Consumer<UserCreatedConsumer>(); // The consumer is registered explicitly this time.
                });
```

I add an `IConsumer` as well

```
public class UserCreatedConsumer : IConsumer<UserCreated>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<UserCreated> context)
    {
        var user = context.Message;
        Debug.WriteLine("My debug string here");
        return TaskUtil.Completed;
    }
}
```

When I create a new user the messages receive the `RabbitMq` (publish rates increase). But then nothing goes on. The total number of messages in the `Queued messages` does not change.

I have two connections (I would expect `IdentityServerService` and `ProfileService`) and I have different queues (I was only expecting one: `user_queue`)

[image]

When I implement the `IConsumer` inside my `IdentityServerService` I receive the message.

I have no error log, warnings or something else.

Anyway... 1) Why does `ProfileService` not receive the message? 2) And why do I have so much queues?

If you need some more information... please tell

**Edit**

When I send a message in the rabbitMq-management my `ProfileService` receive a message, but now I get the following error

```
MassTransit.Messages Error: 0 : R-FAULT 
rabbitmq://localhost/user_queue_new  Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source, 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An exception occurred while deserializing the message envelope ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

Comment: You get temp queues for each service, for request-response. If the message isn't consumed, it's not delivered. Check the bindings for your queue, ensure it is bound to the message exchange. Most probably these classes, although have the same name, are in different namespaces.

Comment: As @AlexeyZimarev says, try to debug bindings between queue and exchange. you can use rabbitmq management to publish message and check if you receive a copy to your queue.